# CSS 3D : rotateY + translateX make elements flicker during in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I need to implement a "room" 3d rotation on some elements; to achieve it `transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg)` and its opposite transition are used. It works fine in Chrome, but **in Firefox** (up to the version 34) the elements flicker during the transition. They can do so just for a moment, having gone half the way, or disappear completely.

What I have noticed: if the `perspective` CSS value on the parent is higher than the computed width of the elements in question - the transition goes well. If the perspective is really a culprit, then I don't understand the nature of such behaviour; the specs say, an element isn't drawn if Z-axis value of **all its points** is lower than the perspective value. And mine should definitely be visible at least partially during the transition.

It should be noted, that only rotateY seems buggy - not the rorateX.

Here are the code samples. The html:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div id="bg-club" class="background club"></div>
    <div id="bg-cafe" class="background cafe active"></div>
    <div id="bg-fitness" class="background fitness"></div>
    <div id="bg-resto" class="background resto"></div>
    <div id="bg-lady" class="background lady"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS (for the sake of convenience the prefixed rules are removed):

```
 .cont{
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:1;
      overflow:hidden;

      perspective:1000px;
      transform-style:preserve-3d;
 }
 .background.active{
      visibility:visible;
      z-index:1;
 }
 .background{
      position:absolute;
      top:50px;
      right:50px;
      bottom:50px;
      left:50px;
      z-index:10;

      backface-visibility: hidden; 
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform-style: preserve-3d; 

      visibility:hidden;
      overflow:hidden;

      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center center;
      background-size:cover;
     }
      .background.cafe{background-color:#987071;}
      .background.club{background-color:#a3367f}
      .background.fitness{background-color:#79728b;}
      .background.lady{background-color:#a6160e;}
      .background.resto{background-color:#712912;}
.rotateRoomLeftOut {
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    animation: rotateRoomLeftOut 4s both ease;
}
.rotateRoomLeftIn {
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    animation: rotateRoomLeftIn 4s both ease;
}

@keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
    to { opacity: .3; transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
    from { opacity: .3; transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
}
```

And here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sss46/9/). By pressing 1-5 yellow boxes we activate the corresponging background animation. The `perspective` here is 1000px, so the *un*desired effect can be achieved by resizing the window.

The other example is [this great set of page 3D transitions](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/). Just navigate to Rotate->Room->Room to Left or Right.

---

**Edit**

Seems that Firefox makes only those elements flicker, whose corresponding dimension (either `width` for `RotateY` or `height` for `rotateX`) is greater than the parent's `perspective`. I haven't yet figured out, why that happens, but the simplest and the most straightforward solution so far is setting the aforementioned perspective greater than the element's dimension. In my case, it would be `100vw` (or `100vmax` to cover both rotate dimensions) for FF 19+ or some other way.

The updated snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var generalEvtAffix = '.hotdot', bodyEl = $('body'), pageContents = $('.sidebar, .center-block'),
  tabsSel = $('.areas [data-toggle="tab"]');
  
 // Анимация фонов на главной
 var bgs = $('.background');
 $('.areas [data-toggle="tab"]').on('click'+generalEvtAffix, function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var thisLink = $(this);
  /* Если уже активен или анимация всё ещё не закончена, ничего не делаем */
  if(thisLink.parent().hasClass('active') || bgs.hasClass('animated'))
   return;
  var bg = $('#bg-'+this.getAttribute('data-bg')),
   bgActive = $('.background.active');
  /* Случайным образом определяем направление анимации. */
  var animationDirs = ["Left"/* , "Top", "Right", "Bottom" */],
   animationDirection = animationDirs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (animationDirs.length) + 0)];
   
  /* - отключаем клик по ссылке на направлении - чтобы временно заблокировать переключение вкладок */
  tabsSel.on('click'+generalEvtAffix+'.clicked', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  });
  
  bgActive.addClass('animated rotateRoom'+animationDirection+'Out')
   .on('animationend.homepage-area-click webkitAnimationEnd.homepage-area-click', function(){
    /* По окончании анимации "Прочь" прошлого активного элемента скрываем его */
    $(this).removeClass('animated active rotateRoom'+animationDirection+'Out')
     .off('animationend.homepage-area-click webkitAnimationEnd.homepage-area-click');
   });
  bg.addClass('animated active rotateRoom'+animationDirection+'In')
   .on('animationend.homepage-area-click webkitAnimationEnd.homepage-area-click', function(event){
    /* По окончании анимации обратно включаем клик. */
    console.log(event);
    $(this).removeClass('animated rotateRoom'+animationDirection+'In')
     .off('animationend.homepage-area-click webkitAnimationEnd.homepage-area-click');;
    tabsSel.off('click'+generalEvtAffix+'.clicked');
   });
 });
 });
```

```css
 .cont{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:1;
 overflow:hidden;
 
 -webkit-perspective:1000px;
 -moz-perspective:1000px;
 perspective:1000px;
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .cont{
     perspective:100vw;   
    }
}
.background.active{
 visibility:visible;
 z-index:1;
}
.background{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 right:50px;
 bottom:50px;
 left:50px;
    z-index:10;
 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden; 
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d; 
 
 visibility:hidden;
  overflow:hidden;
 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 background-size:cover;
}
 .background.cafe{
  background-color:#987071;
    }
    .background.club{
  background-color:#a3367f
 }
 .background.fitness{
  background-color:#79728b;
 }
 .background.lady{
  background-color:#a6160e;
 }
 .background.resto{
  background-color:#712912;
 }
/* Классы анимации фона типа "Room" */
 .rotateRoomLeftOut {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: rotateRoomLeftOut 4s both ease;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-animation: rotateRoomLeftOut 4s both ease;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: rotateRoomLeftOut 4s both ease;
 }
 .rotateRoomLeftIn {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: rotateRoomLeftIn 4s both ease;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -moz-animation: rotateRoomLeftIn 4s both ease;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  animation: rotateRoomLeftIn 4s both ease;
 }
/* Описание анимаций */

 @-webkit-keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
  to { opacity: .3; -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
  to { opacity: .3; -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
 }
 @keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
  to { opacity: .3; transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
  from { opacity: .3; -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
  from { opacity: .3; -moz-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
 }
 @keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
  from { opacity: .3; transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
 }
.areas{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;z-index:1000;
}
.areas li a{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:yellow;
    margin:5px;
    color:black;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="bg-club" class="background club"></div>
  <div id="bg-cafe" class="background cafe active"></div>
  <div id="bg-fitness" class="background fitness"></div>
  <div id="bg-resto" class="background resto"></div>
  <div id="bg-lady" class="background lady"></div>
 </div>

<ul class="areas text-center content-section">
  <li><a href="#club" class="club" data-target="[data-tab='club']" data-bg="club" data-toggle="tab">1</a>
  </li><li class="active"><a href="#cafe" class="cafe" data-target="[data-tab='cafe']" data-bg="cafe" data-toggle="tab">2</a>
  </li><li><a href="#fitness" class="fitness" data-target="[data-tab='fitness']" data-bg="fitness" data-toggle="tab">3</a>
  </li><li><a href="#resto" class="resto" data-target="[data-tab='resto']" data-bg="resto" data-toggle="tab">4</a>
  </li><li><a href="#lady" class="lady" data-target="[data-tab='lady']" data-bg="lady" data-toggle="tab">5</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Still looking forward for a reason behind this behavior.

Comment: @JohanVdR, sorry, but did you look in my code samples? The transitions don't need to pretend they are 3D - they already *are* 3D ones. The `backface-visibility` is turned to hidden already (and I tried that on the parent element as well, with no effect).

Comment: Maybe add more keyframes. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid--webdesign-4867

Comment: Originally I assumed you were talking about the lack of antialiasing along the top border of your fiddle, but you’re actually seeing flickering/disappearing panels are you? On my system (latest Nightly, Yosemite public preview 2) it looks fine (apart from the aforementioned aliasing). Is it still a problem for you? What GPU are you running and are your drivers up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason it is flickering is because Mozilla is detecting the object as out of view.
if your perspective is 1000px, and something with a width of 1100px rotates, then the edge of the element will pass behind you and out of view, which mozilla may determine as "do not render"

the only solution I can offer for a consistent view is to set perspective to something like 100vw to make sure your perspective is always as far as your screen is wide